# How to display inline blocks without breaking them on new line when shrinking parent

Tags: html, width, css

I have 2 columns (inline blocks) in a container (100% width).

1. Left side column has to have a min-width, say 200px, width:25%.
2. Right side column has width:75%

   ```
   <style>
   .outer {
       width: 100%;
       border: 1px solid black;
   }
   .left, .right {
       display:inline-block;
   }
   .left {
       min-width: 200px;
       width: 25%;
       background-color: #dcc2c2;
   }
   .right {
       width: 75%;
       background-color: #d0dee8;
   }
   </style>

       <div class="outer">
           <div class="left">left</div>
           <div class="right">right</div>
       </div>
   ```

Until the min-width is reached when resizing, the columns sit side by side which is what I want, but once the min-width kicks in, the right column falls on the next line.

How can I make the right column to shrink but not fall on the next line ?

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bqvg/)

Comment: you can use `calc()` to limit the `max-width` of the right column http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/4Bqvg/4/ However `calc()` is not supported by IE8 (and below)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:hidden` to outer:

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4Bqvg/6/)**

Comment: Your fix doesn't work well for all situations as you can see here: [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vogb32g8/)

Comment: I've just met this magical solution and searching around, this is the closest I found. [MDN doc only talks about `white-space`'s effects on text rather than elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), making this even more mysterious. Do you have anything that explains why this works?

Comment: If you use a minifier or a compiler, like Webpack, you don't have to worry about that white space being created by line feeds.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `calc(100% - 200px)` keep spaces for it to work!

```
.right {
    width:75%;
    max-width:calc(100% - 200px);
    background-color: #d0dee8;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bqvg/5/)

[Info about css3 calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: Keep in mind it does not work in IE8 or older (see info about css3 calc() link in my answer). If this works for you, please accept my answer. Otherwise accept @j08691

Comment: Yea, knew that it doesn't work in IE8 or older, thanks again for reminding. But as you said @j08691's solution seems to be working too.

Comment: Calc is nice, just be aware that it can be performance heavy if used a lot. This goes for most math oriented functionality.

Comment: best solution i was trying flex and I was also making exact percentages but this is the best answer i've seen all week